# All possible combinations for 3 digits of list never the same

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, combinations, formula

I have a list that looks like:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

How do I solve this to find all combinations for 3 digits.  The same letter cannot be used in same row.

```
ABC
ABD
ABE
ABF
ABG
AGB
```

E.g something like...:

```
x = ['a','b','c','d','e']
n = 3
import itertools
aa = [list(comb) for i in range(1, n+2) for comb in itertools.combinations(x, i)]
print(aa)
```

This does not give desired input:

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'd'], ['a', 'e'], ['b', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['b', 'e'], ['c'
```

Comment: I think you are close.  I am not 100% sure I understand what your desired output is though.  I used ```aa = [list(comb) for i in range(3, 4) for comb in itertools.combinations(x, i)]``` to get ```[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'e'], ['a', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python Standard Library [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) already has the functionality you are trying to implement. Also you are using it in your code (funnily).

`itertools.combinations(a,3)` returns all 3-combinations of the a. To convert that to "list of list" you should use `.extend()` as follows;

```
x = ['a','b','c','d','e']
n = 3
import itertools
permutations = []
combinations = []
combinations.extend(itertools.combinations(x,n))
permutations.extend(itertools.permutations(x,n))

print("Permutations;", permutations)
print("\n")
print("Combinations;", combinations)
```

> Additionally, I suggest you to search on "[Combination, Permutation Difference](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html)". As I understood from your question; permutation is what you want. (If you run the code I shared, you will understand the difference easliy.)

Answer (score 0):

To understand how the solution process works, try the following:

```
# get all combinations of n items from given list
def getCombinations(items, n):
    if len(items) < n: return [] # need more items than are remaining 
    if n == 0: return [''] # need no more items, return the combination of no items

    [fst, *rst] = items

    # all combinations including the first item in the list
    including = [fst + comb for comb in getCombinations(rst, n-1)]

    # all combinations excluding the first item in the list
    excluding = getCombinations(rst, n)

    both = including + excluding
    return both

x = ['a','b','c','d','e']
n = 3
print(getCombinations(x, n))
# ['abc', 'abd', 'abe', 'acd', 'ace', 'ade', 'bcd', 'bce', 'bde', 'cde']
```

Comment: This generates combinations, but not permutations. i.e. it includes `abc` and not `bac`. It assumes that the elements in the list supplied are unique, meaning if you give it `['a', 'a', 'b']` you will get two `'ab'`s.

Comment: I'm a little confused at the difference.    Permutations seem to give more possible combinations with none the same?

Answer (score 0):

combinations works on strings not lists, so you should first turn it into a string using: `''.join(x)`

```
from itertools import combinations
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
n = 3
aa = combinations(''.join(x), n)
for comb in aa:
    print(''.join(comb))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
abc
abd
abe
acd
ace
ade
bcd
bce
bde
cde
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
[''.join(comb) for comb in combinations(''.join(x), n)]
```